# Different DLL versions, one codebase

Tags: c#, inheritance, dll

In my projects I have to interact with an ERP system that exposes about 30 different API DLLs.
The ERP company systematically creates new versions of their system and I'm forced to change the DLLs to the new versions. However, not all of my clients update the ERP, so I'm also forced to maintain old references. My current solution to this problem is:

1) For every ERP version I create an 'ApiWrapper' project, referencing the DLLs for this ERP version.

2) In my main project I reference those 'ApiWrappers' and use a selected one of those.

An example function inside of the 'ApiWrapper' looks like this:

```
public void AddContractorAttribute(Ustawienia settings, string attributeCode, string attributeValue, int contractorId)
    {
        CreateNewSession();

        CDNHeal.Kontrahenci AllContractors = (CDNHeal.Kontrahenci)session.CreateObject("CDN.Kontrahenci", null);
        CDNHeal.IKontrahent SelectedContractor = (CDNHeal.IKontrahent)AllContractors[$"Knt_KntId = {contractorId}"];
        CDNBase.ICollection AllAttributes = (CDNBase.ICollection)(session.CreateObject("CDN.DefAtrybuty", null));
        CDNTwrb1.IDefAtrybut SelectedAttribute = (CDNTwrb1.IDefAtrybut)AllAttributes[$"dea_Kod = '{attributeCode}'"];
        CDNTwrb1.IKntAtrybut NewAttributeValue = (CDNTwrb1.IKntAtrybut)SelectedContractor.Atrybuty.AddNew(null);

        NewAttributeValue.DefAtrybut = (CDNTwrb1.DefAtrybut)SelectedAttribute;
        NewAttributeValue.Wartosc = attributeValue;

        session.Save();
    }
```

Now, the problem I have is: if I want to add or change a function in the ApiWrapper, I have to do it in every single one of those. They don't differ code-wise, they only reference a different set of DLLs. Is there a way to solve this issue through class inheritance or otherwise?

Comment: _"They don't differ code-wise"_ - so different versions do not change API or behavior (outside bug fixes) nor do they add new features?

Comment: If the interfaces of the API remain the same it would be easier to [redirect the assembly versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions).

Comment: Most of the time - nothing changes for me. Yes, they add new functions and bugfixes, but I only cover a selected set of functions inside of the API so I don't have to change my code. For my project to work with a new ERP version, I only need to reference the new API DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

You can design a class that will be implemented with the builder pattern or factory method (use some creational pattern, please read about these patterns it will help you reduce your codebase). The approach is to design one generic class which will be used everywhere. So, you can modify it easily. You need to figure out how to distinguish your dlls. Dll's References could be distinguished in two ways:

1. by the full name of the assembly (usually it includes the version
   of assembly).
2. or you can load all dlls into memory and
       reflectively read dll's version.

After distinguishing versions you can easily put all dlls together and ship it. 
So, basically you should design a generic builder, which will take a version number as a parameter and return a well-prepared bench of dlls.
Hope it helps.